# Optional parameter in function definition and its usage syntax

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I have defined a method definition with optional named parameter.

```dart
class PostBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List<Submission>> Function({String? next}) postFetcher;
  ...
  ...
}
```

I can able to invoke that function as expected like below.

```dart
class _PostBuilderState extends State<PostBuilder> {
   ...
   ...
   
   _fetch() async {
     var posts = await widget.postFetcher();
     // or
     var posts = await widget.postFetcher(next: _items.getLast()?.name);
   }
```

But unfortunately, I cannot figure our how to use it properly and don't know the correct syntax.

```dart
PostBuilder((next) => getPosts(next))
```

This is syntax error that is being thrown by the compiler

```
error: The argument type 'Future<List<Submission>> Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<Submission>> Function({String? next})'. (argument_type_not_assignable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postFetcher` takes a named parameter.  If you want to assign an anonymous function to it, that anonymous function also must take a named parameter.  The syntax for anonymous functions is the same as for named functions (the types for anonymous functions are usually omitted because they can be inferred).  You therefore want:

```dart
PostBuilder(({next}) => getPosts(next))
```